# Ribbon with border in it

Tags: css, html

It is possible to create ribbon with border inside. I have created default ribbon like this:

[Ribbon without borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKVGV.jpg)

But I need ribbon like this. I cannot use images.

[Ribbon with border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNuca.jpg)

What is the best possible solution?

Comment: You wont get the 45° angle without images. Id do it illustrator and export it as SVG, which would be the cleanest solution I guess (IE9+ browser support); Edit ok there is -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); but Id still do it in SVG (technically as much as an image as html +css)

Comment: can you post a fiddle or your code you used to create the one without borders

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u2o1k8jp/1/ somethink like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/pe42afh6/) is the best I could do.

```
h1 span:before, h1 span:after {
    content: "";
    height: 90%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    width: 70px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
h1 span:before {
    right: 100%;
    border-left: 0 none;
}
h1 span:after {
    left: 100%;
    border-right: 0 none;
}

h1:before, h1:after {
    content: "";
    height: 31px;
    width: 31px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

h1:before {
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
    right: calc(100% + 70px - 16px);
}
h1:after {
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    left: calc(100% + 70px - 16px);
}
```

**Notes**:

- Won't work with older browsers that don't support: `transform`, `calc`, `:before` and `:after`
- This works with any length of the title, however if you change the font-size, you'll have to change the width and height of `h1:before, h1:after` manually.